# Firebase Pagination: After Using queryLimitedToFirst How do I get Next?

Tags: objective-c, pagination, firebase

I have been using Firebase to store data. It seems to have a very simple queryLimitedToFirst as well as to last function, but I cannot seem to find away to get the next set of data.

I am writing in Objective C. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: You take the last key/value of the first set and pass that into `queryStartingAt...`. But without seeing your actual code, it's difficult to say more.

Comment: i have the same issue can you post your code?